# How could I make this code more React - like

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React and I want to learn to write it better. I tried Googling for answers for this matter but I can't seem to find anything useful.

I have a list of projects which are objects with id (not a number, but a string), name, and target. I want to create another list of new objects which also have the sum of donations and minDonations values. Those I get from another list `"donations"`. The lists are separate since I get them from two different `APIs`.

I managed to get the information I wanted and to create a new list of objects from them, but this seems very `unReact-like` way of doing this. How could I make this code better?

I hope this is the right place for this kind of question.

Thank you in advance.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        //use the data gathered to create new list of object containing
        //the project and the amount invested/targeted to them and minDonations value
        var helperProjectList = projects.map(p => {
            const projectObject = {
                id: p.id,
                name: p.name,
                target: p.target,
                minDonations: 0,
                sum: 0
            }
            return projectObject
        })
 
        for (var p = 0; p < helperProjectList.length; p++) {
            for (var d = 0; d < donations.length; d++) {
                if (donations[d].target == helperProjectList[p].id) {
                    helperProjectList[p].sum += donations[d].sum
                    helperProjectList[p].minDonations += donations[d].sum
                }
            }
        }
        //this cant be on the for loops above for it loops too many times.
        var ut = 0;
        for(var d = 0; d < donations.length; d++) {
            if (donations[d].target === undefined) {
                ut += donations[d].sum
            }
        }

        setProjectDonations(helperProjectList)
        setUnTargetedDonationsSum(ut)
    }, [projects, donations])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //use the data gathered to create new list of object containing
  //the project and the amount invested/targeted to them and minDonations value
  var helperProjectList = projects.map((p) => {
    const foundIndex = donations?.findIndex(donation => donation.target == p.id);
    if(foundIndex !== -1){
      return {
        id: p.id,
        name: p.name,
        target: p.target,
        minDonations: donations[foundIndex].minDonations + p.minDonations,
        sum: donations[foundIndex].sum + p.sum,
      };
    }else {
      return {
        id: p.id,
        name: p.name,
        target: p.target,
        minDonations: 0,
        sum: 0,
      };
    }
  });
  var ut = 0;
  for (var d = 0; d < donations.length; d++) {
    if (donations[d].target === undefined) {
      ut += donations[d].sum;
    }
  }

  setProjectDonations(helperProjectList);
  setUnTargetedDonationsSum(ut);
}, [projects, donations]);
```

Comment: This is much better code compared to what I had, but it does not take into account that many donations can have same target, which is my main reason looping